# Nuxt.js SSR w/ Nest API deployed to AWS in a Docker container

Tags: docker, axios, nuxt.js, nestjs

I've tried roughly 5 million variations on the theme here, as well as spent a lot of time poring through the Nuxt docs and I cannot get Nuxt SSR with a Nest backend working when deployed in a docker container to AWS. Below is my current setup. Please let me know if I've left anything out.

Here are the errors I'm getting:

https://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com/contact
This route makes a `POST` request for page meta to `https://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com/api/contact/meta` in the component's `asyncData` method. This produces a big old error from Axios. Below is the part I think is relevant, but let me know if you need more.

```
{
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'xxx.xx.x.x', // IP Address of the docker container
  port: 443,
  config: {
    url: 'https://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com/api/contact/meta',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      connection: 'close',
      'x-real-ip': 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', // My IP
      'x-forwarded-for': 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', // My IP
      'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
      'x-forwarded-ssl': 'on',
      'x-forwarded-port': '443',
      pragma: 'no-cache',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36',
      'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
      'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
      'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
      'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    baseURL: 'https://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com'
  }
```

Here's the relevant part of my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
mode: 'universal',
srcDir: './src',
rootDir: './',
modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios'],
// NOTE: I get the same errors if I leave this block out
server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3002
},
```

When I deploy I use a `Dockerfile` that copies all the needed files from my project directory into the container, runs `yarn install`, exposes port 3002, runs `yarn build.prod`, and ends with `CMD ["yarn", "start"]` (see below for relevant `package.json` scripts).

```
"scripts": {
    "clean.nuxt": "rimraf .nuxt",
    "build.client": "nuxt build",
    "build.server": "tsc -p tsconfig.server.json", // Transpile TypeScript from `src/server` into `.nuxt/api`
    "build.prod": "run-s clean.nuxt build.client build.server",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node .nuxt/api/index.js",
}
```

The docker image is built locally and pushed to an ECR repo. I then SSH into my server and run `docker-compose up -d` with this compose file:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  my_service:
  image: link/to/my/image:${TAG:-prod}
  container_name: my_container
  hostname: www.noticeeverythingcreative.com
  restart: unless-stopped

ports:
  # Http Port
  - 3002:3002

networks:
  - web-network # External (the actual compose file also has the corresponding networks block at the bottom)

environment:
  - NODE_ENV=production
  - API_URL=https://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com
  - HOST=www.noticeeverythingcreative.com
  - PORT=3002
  - VIRTUAL_PORT=3002
```

Here's my server-side controller that handles Nuxt rendering:

**src/server/app/nuxt.controller.ts**

```
import { Controller, Get, Request, Response } from '@nestjs/common';
import { join, resolve } from 'path';
import * as config from 'config';

const { Builder, Nuxt } = require('nuxt');
const nuxtConfig = require(join(resolve(), 'nuxt.config.js'));

@Controller()
export class NuxtController
{
    nuxt:any;

    constructor()
    {
        this.nuxt = new Nuxt(nuxtConfig);
        const Env = config as any;

        // Build only in dev mode
        if (Env.name === 'development')
        {
            const builder = new Builder(this.nuxt);
            builder.build();
        }
        else
        {
            this.nuxt.ready();
        }

    }

    @Get('*')
    async root(@Request() req:any, @Response() res:any)
    {
        if (this.nuxt)
        {
            return await this.nuxt.render(req, res);
        }
        else
        {
            res.send('Nuxt is disabled.');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the client-side contact component's `asyncData` and `head` implementations:

```
async asyncData(ctx:any)
{
    // fetch page meta from API
    try
    {
        const meta = await ctx.$axios(<any>{
            method: 'post',
            url: `${ ctx.env.apiHost }/contact/meta`,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        });

        return { meta: meta.data };
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        // Redirect to error page or 404 depending on server response
        console.log('ERR: ', error);
    }
}

head()
{
    return this.$data.meta;
}
```

The issues I'm having only occur in the production environment on the production host. Locally I can run `yarn build.prod && cross-env NODE_ENV=development node .nuxt/api/index.js` and the app runs and renders without error.

**Update**

If I allow the Nuxt app to actually run on localhost inside the docker container, I end up with the opposite problem. For example, if I change my nuxt.config.js server and axios blocks to

```
server: {
    port: 3002, // default: 3000,
},
axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3002'
}
```

And change the request to:

```
const meta = await ctx.$axios(<any>{
    method: 'post',
    // NOTE: relative path here instead of the absolute path above
    url: `/api/contact/meta`,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
});

return { meta: meta.data };
```

A fresh load of https://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com/contact renders fine. This can be confirmed by viewing the page source and seeing that the title has been updated and that there are no console errors. However, if you load the home page (https://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com) and click the contact link in the nav, you'll see `POST http://localhost:3002/api/contact/meta net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

NOTE: this is the version that is deployed as of the last edit of this question.

Comment: Just tested and got the error:
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/.nuxt/server/app/email/img/gh.png'
based on the error it might be possible that the nest controller path matches aren't correct and the request is trying to load content from the nuxt app instead of Nest API endpoints. That thought seems validated by the fact that https://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com/api/ renders an Nuxt error page instead of a 404 or expected API error. Can you share the details of the controller rules you have?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear that form submission is not an issue. Just the rendering of the page, specifically the POST request to /api/contact/meta. There are no server-side handlers for any GET requests other than the one in NuxtController in the above snippet.

Comment: In other words, I’m pretty sure this is a networking issue rather than a logic one. Sorry if that’s not clear.

Comment: I see - can you share the snippet making the call for the form to compare and contrast? One thing I'd try to is to make all the URLs from axios requests relative instead of prepending the apiHost since you're making calls to the same host as the origin.

Comment: The form submission call is identical except for the form data and the endpoint. And it definitely works. I just deployed the bad image path fix. And I actually see your bounced email from test@test.com. I've actually tried the relative path and that fails because even with the Axios `baseURL` set properly it still sends the request to `localhost:3002`.

Comment: Here's the form submission call, anyway: `this.$axios({
   method: 'post',
   url: `${ this.env.apiHost }/contact`,
   data: this.formValue,
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  }).then(...)`

Comment: Just noticed a difference. Isn't the `$axios` module available at `ctx.app.$axios` instead of `ctx.$axios`?

Comment: That's not entirely clear to me from Nuxt's docs. In practice it looks like if I use an Axios instance as a plugin, it's available as `ctx.app.$whateverICalledIt`, whereas the default implementation in Nuxt places it directly on the context. At least it appears to work that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207132/discussion-between-mycompassspins-and-david-t).

Comment: Sorry I missed that message yesterday, but saw your reply. Have you tried not providing axios with a baseURL and just used the relative path? While I don't serve nuxt from Nest like you've shown, I do use the proxy features to relay to my API and just provide relative paths for everything with no baseURL successfully.

Comment: Eliminating the baseURL causes an in-app request to be made on the default port 3000 when using a relative path. I suppose I could run the app in docker on 3000 and map 3002 on my host to 3000 in the container, but I feel like it shouldn't be this much of an issue to use whatever port I want.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution, but I don't love it, so if anyone has anything better, please post.

I got it working by allowing the Nuxt app to run on localhost inside the docker container, but making the http requests to the actual host (e.g., `https://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com/whatever`).

So, in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
// The server and axios blocks simply serve to set the port as something other than the default 3000
server: {
    port: 3002, // default: 3000,
},
axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3002'
},
env: {
    apiHost: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
        'https://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com/api' :
        'http://localhost:3002/api'
}
```

In `docker-compose.yml` I removed anything that would make the host anything but localhost, as well as any env variables that nuxt is counting on (mostly because I can't quite figure out how those work in Nuxt, except that it's not the way I would expect):

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  my_service:
  image: link/to/my/image:${TAG:-prod}
  container_name: my_container
  # REMOVED
  # hostname: www.noticeeverythingcreative.com
  restart: unless-stopped

ports:
  # Http Port
  - 3002:3002

networks:
  - web-network # External (the actual compose file also has the corresponding networks block at the bottom)

environment:
  # REMOVED
  # - API_URL=https://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com
  # - HOST=www.noticeeverythingcreative.com
  - NODE_ENV=production
  - PORT=3002
  - VIRTUAL_PORT=3002
```

And when making api requests:

```
// NOTE: ctx.env.apiHost is https://www.noticeeverythingcreative.com/api
const meta = await ctx.$axios(<any>{
    method: 'post',
    url: `${ ctx.env.apiHost }/contact/meta`,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
});

return { meta: meta.data };
```